# How to integrate android annotation in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-annotations

Followed [these](http://juranosaurus.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-annotation-setting.html) steps to configure `android annotation` dependencies in project. Link of official [documentation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/SharedPreferencesHelpers#defining-the-preferences).

Now created a `sharedPreference` class in project:

```
@SharedPref(value = SharedPref.Scope.UNIQUE)
public interface SampleApp {
  @DefaultInt(0)
  int appOpenedCount();

  @DefaultInt(0)
  int appOpenedCountVersionSpecific();
}
```

I am trying to access these `preferences` in android class:

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
@EApplication
public class HuntApp extends Application {

private static HuntApp appInstance;
private static Context mContext;
public static SampleApp_ appPref;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appPref = new SampleApp_(this);
}
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
Error:(19, 19) error: cannot find symbol class SampleApp_
```

I re-confirmed the dependencies and steps but couldn't able to build the project. What I am doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciable.

## Edit-1  AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:name=".HuntApp_"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity_"></activity>

</application>
```

## Edit-2 module gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
}

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "com.app.huntapp"
        logLevel 'INFO'
        logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.huntapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `import`? Try rebuilding your project.

Comment: Sorry. didn't get it. what import?

Comment: I mean the `import` line of SampleApp_ class in HuntApp.

Comment: tried but got this `Error:(25, 5) error: org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref can only be used on an element that extends org.androidannotations.api.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesHelper` which seems to be correct

Comment: Maybe @Pref can't be used in a `@EApplication` bean, but just in `@EActivity`, `@EBean` and so on.

Comment: BTW it's not working in `@EActivity` too. BTW I have used it before in `@EApplicaiton` :(

Comment: Strange. I just import  add "`import com.app.gymhunt.sampleApp_`" and try to access it `@Pref SampleApp_ pref;` and it worked :P

Comment: Great! ;) glad to work

Comment: Lol! and it's not working again (just after rebuilding the project)

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle` you have to put this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

and in dependencies block:

```
apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.0.0'
compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.0.0'
```

Then, you can't instantiate prefs class. You have to inject it using `@Pref`:

```
@Pref
SampleApp prefs;
```

Comment: Please checkout the Edit-2 section. I have put my module gradle file.